# Alternative Category layout at different url

Tags: category, layout, template

I have a store setup with a top level category called Products, containing multiple sub-categories, and products have both the Products category and a sub-category assigned.  list.phtml is set up such that it displays all products broken up into sub-categories if you are viewing the top level Products category, or just the products in the particular sub-category otherwise.

The client would like Wholesale users to have the option of a different layout for the Products category page.  So at /products.html, they will see what any visitor sees, but then at /wholesale.html, they will see all of the same products from the Products category, but in a different layout (probably showing the appropriate price tier and password protected so only wholesale group members can see it).

I'm still pretty new to Magento, and don't know how to create this alternate layout/url that displays all of the items in Products.  Would someone advise me on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make wholesale a new category and set all the products in it. Or maybe just use https://github.com/firegento/firegento-dynamiccategory for this, then you only have to put the products in one category and the second is built automatically

Then you can style the category either with its own layout handle `<CATEGORY_--ID-->` or with the `custom_layout`